# Omniauth - Facebook app doesn't run callback url after successful Facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I am having an issue with Omniauth.

Here is what I want to do(at least what I understood  `devise_token_auth` documentation):

1. Log in/signing up from client side using Facebook Login
2. After a succesful log in, my facebook app has to run the callback url(provided by onminauth: www.abcdefg.com/auth/facebook/callback)
3. The callback creates a user account in my database

The problem I am encountering is that, after a successful login, my Facebook app doesn't run the callback.

Here is a screenshot of my fb app config:
[image: screen shot 2016-04-18 at 12 45 40]

On my Ruby-On-Rails side:

On my gemfile:

`gem 'devise_token_auth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'`

in config/initizializers/omniauth.rb

`Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
           :scope => 'email,user_birthday'
end`

Here is my callback route(from rake routes):
`/auth/:provider/callback` -- I've replaced :provider by facebook

If you think it is not the right way to implement a facebook login, please feel free to correct me.

Comment: This is not actually a “callback” – Facebook just redirects the user back to the address in their own browser, after they confirmed the login dialog. What URL gets redirected to, depends on the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the login dialog call – so go check that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Devise gem for authentication, refer below link for complete details:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

And otherwise you can refer to below answer:
https://medium.com/@euniceschoi/facebook-oauth-with-rails-33fc8c1a4e58